# database web service visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, web-services

can someone tell me usefull tutorials that explain how to create web services in visual studio in c#? What im trying to do is a webservice that access to database and allows to make crud operations in a table on a SQLServer database.
What i need is a tutorial that explains how to create a database in SQL ce and SQL Express Edition and how to create a database web service in visual studio 2010 in c#.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an article to get you started: [A First Step in a Simple WCF Web Service...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alina/archive/2009/01/05/a-simple-wcf-web-service-using-entity-framework.aspx)

- Sounds like you want a SQL CE 4 database. Here's a [high level view using SQL CE Embedded Database in your ASP.NET project](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx).
- Or.... wait, did you want it a SQL Server database? [How To Create a SQL Server Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186312.aspx). Express is just a SKU meaning 'free' and 'has certain limitations'.
- The WCF article uses Entity Framework. Choose the data access you like (LINQ To SQL, plain ADO.NET, SubSonic, whatever)

Comment: so your advice is to install SQL Server 2008 Enterprise?

Comment: @fegol: I'm not sure where you got the 'Enterprise' suggestion. Stick with Express; it likely has no limitation that you'll run into.

Comment: Because Enterprise brings Management Studio, Express does not

Comment: @fegol: Download SSMS Express for free here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b